# How to make tint slider with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-processing, bootstrap-4

1. Please show me how to make tint slider in **javascript** ( like below image ):
[image]

2. Is there any **javascript** filter library which support to make **photo effect** : enhance hues and strengthen the separation of colors ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add code to show your efforts so far.